# CloudFront Distribution with OpenIdc Authenticated WebApp

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, amazon-cloudfront

I have a web application (hosted on EC2s fronted by ALB) that is authenticated with OpenID Connect (Ping Fed provider), and we are thinking to create AWS Cloudfront distribution on top of it so global users get better performance.

When I read Cloudfront documentation, it say that custom origin application need to be publicly available (from documentation "for CloudFront to get your files from an HTTP server, the files must remain publicly accessible").

Does this mean that I need to remove OpenID AuthN and instead use signed URLs or cookies and if AuthN to be removed then what's the trigger to know that the user is logged in and I could generate either signed urls/cookies for Cloudfront.

There are posts that mentions doing this with Lambda@Edge but I want to avoid too many moving pieces.

Comment: Given the answer that has been received, my guess is that this question is not in an answerable state. I will try to put it on hold for now.

Answer (score 0):

How your web app is architected very much affects where you can host:

- Single Page Apps are just static content will fit nicely with CloudFront, since the UI page itself does not disclose anything sensitive
- Web Apps that issue Cookies typically will instead require a server side in a language such as .Net or Java, and downloading a page also includes data

I have quite a bit of experience with the first case. Please post a bit more about your scenario and I may be able to point you to some resources that help.